# Media Capture WinRT SetPreviewRotation working but causing display issue.

Tags: c#, rotation, windows-runtime, webcam

I've downloaded the sample here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622

I have compiled and everything runs perfectly. However I want to rotate the camera so that it is in portrait mode. After consulting the documentation I found the following code:

MediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise270Degrees) 
and 
MediaCapture.SetRecordRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise270Degrees).

I have added the two lines above and it has indeed rotated the output which is exactly what I am after. The only issue is the preview now has an orange and blue distortion running through it. The Recording one worked perfectly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code for the preview:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="previewCanvas1" Width="576" Height="720" Background="Gray">

   <CaptureElement x:Name="previewElement1" Width="720" Height="576"   RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" >

     <CaptureElement.RenderTransform>
       <RotateTransform Angle="270" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
     </CaptureElement.RenderTransform>

   </CaptureElement>

</Canvas>
```